# Where does Windows store Bing Dynamic Theme's wallpapers?

Tags: windows, themes, bing

I'm wondering where does Windows store [Bing Dynamic Theme](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/bing-dynamic-theme)'s wallpapers? Or for that matter any other rss themes?

Comment: I hope this link will give your answer http://www.redmondpie.com/bing-dynamic-theme-for-windows-7-refreshes-your-wallpaper-automatically-via-rss-feed/

Comment: `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\Best of B\DesktopBackground` I think they are here.

Comment: Nope! It's not there either.

Comment: I use a windows mobile I want to know location of image from the Bing wallpaper which comes. Phone is Lumia 800.

Comment: @RegisteredUser Please create a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Personalization -> Desktop Background, and you should see the location right above the pictures themselves. In my case, it's:
**%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Enclosure\{some-guid}**

Edit: per the other answer, the path has been changed to:
**%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\BingDesktop\themes**

I'm not using Windows 7 anymore myself, so I can't verify this.

[image]

Comment: Well, it's weird! Mine says the same thing but when I follow the path, the folder named `Enclosure` does not exists!

Comment: @WalkingMan Okay, try this. When you downloaded the theme, an RSS feed was added to IE. This feed checks for new wallpapers and downloads them. So open IE, open the **Favorites** panel, click on **Feeds** and find the feed for the Bing theme (the name should be an URL starting with http://themeserver.microsoft.com). Right-click on the feed and select **Properties**. Make sure that "Automatically download attached files" is checked, and click on "View files". This should open the location where the images are downloaded.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention it here. The path mentioned above actually does exist but Windows doesn't display it no matter what you do. You just have to type the address in address bar to get there.

Comment: New path seems to be C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\BingDesktop\en-US\Apps\Wallpaper_<Some GUID>\VersionIndependent\images

Comment: Yeah, new path -- see below.

Answer (score 1):

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\BingDesktop\themes
```